# Specific array merge with dates in php

Tags: php, array-merge

I've got two arrays:

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => "1 Oct 2016"
  1 => "2 Oct 2016"
  2 => "3 Oct 2016"
  3 => "4 Oct 2016"
  4 => "5 Oct 2016"
]
```

and

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => "29 Sep 2016"
  1 => "30 Sep 2016"
  2 => "1 Oct 2016"
  3 => "2 Oct 2016"
  4 => "3 Oct 2016"
]
```

I need to merge them into one with sort by date to get something like this:

```
array:7 [▼
  0 => "29 Sep 2016"
  1 => "30 Sep 2016"
  2 => "1 Oct 2016"
  3 => "2 Oct 2016"
  4 => "3 Oct 2016"
  5 => "4 Oct 2016"
  6 => "5 Oct 2016"
]
```

How can i do this?

Comment: So, you want to merge, sort, and then remove duplicates?  There are separate array functions for each of these actions that you can use.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) (to get one array), [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) (to eliminate duplicates) and [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) (to get them in the right order):

```
$c = array_unique(array_merge($a, $b));
usort($c, function($a, $b) { return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b); });
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/675096).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't think it would be so easy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function _sort($a, $b)
{
    $a = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M Y', $a);
    $b = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M Y', $b);

    if ($a == $b) return 0;

    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a =  [
  0 => "1 Oct 2016",
  1 => "2 Oct 2016",
  2 => "3 Oct 2016",
  3 => "4 Oct 2016",
  4 => "5 Oct 2016",
];

$b = [
  0 => "29 Sep 2016",
  1 => "30 Sep 2016",
  2 => "1 Oct 2016",
  3 => "2 Oct 2016",
  4 => "3 Oct 2016",
];

$merged = array_merge($a, $b);
# sort
usort($merged, '_sort');

print_r($merged);
```